# Iphone URL schemes : Back to app

Tags: iphone, url, ios5

I am opening an another app using openUrl of url scheme.Now I want to back to my source app getting some information from target app.Can anyone know how it will be done?
I am able to open other app using apple url scheme but not getting how it will be returned to previous app.I am using following code to open target app.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't, only if the app you are opening knows how to app your app, end knows that your app is the one that opened it will it be able to open your app again.

There is no standaard URL scheme that can tell an other app to open your again.

Answer (score 1):

if the target app yours as well, or it is not but it supports calling back out?

If so, you pass it your URL as a parameter:

url = `@"otherapp://?return=myapp";`

Comment: target app is not my app.So I have no control of it.

Answer (score 0):

Latest update from iOS 9: 
Now apple provide back button by default when you navigate to any app using url schemes.

Here you go:

http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/08/09/how-to-use-the-new-back-button-in-ios-9